# How do you query a collection whose documents have a reference field and use the reference field data for the query?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with documents that have a reference field and I want to get documents with a certain value in the reference field.

e.g.

```
firestore.collection("collect1")
         .whereEqualTo("reference.type", type1)
         .orderBy("reference.date", DESC)
         .get()
```

Is something like above possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get documents with a certain value in the reference field.

This is definitely possible. If you pass to the [whereEqualTo(String field, Object value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method as the second argument a reference, your query will work perfectly fine.

> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should be equal to the specified value.

So be sure that the `type1` object is of type DocumentReference. Should look similar to this:

```
projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/[DATABASE_ID]/documents/[DOCUMENT_PATH]
```